# Expose a single entity GET operation in OData

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

This question is probably due to my limited understanding of Microsoft's OData implementation.

With the C# "Reflection Data Provider", I'm trying to support URLs such as `http://localhost/Users(2)`, but I can't figure out how.

I have `http://localhost/Users` working, which currently simply returns all available users. It is implemented as a property `public IQueryable<User> Users` on an `IUpdatable` child class.

I see a lot of OData client examples flying around with the bracket syntax. How can I serve this in C#? Or, if this syntax does not work, what is the recommended way to get a *single* entity using WCF, OData and the Reflection Data Provider?

Note: our OData API does not at all map directly to a relational database, so "just" using the Entity Framework provider and magically getting everything for free is not an option.

Comment: Have you defined a key for `Users` using `DataServiceKeyAttribute`?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?  This should work out of the box whether or not you're using EF.  I suspect either you don't have a key column defined or you've modified the routing to prevent this syntax.

Comment: probably you don't have a user with id=2. What error did you get?

Comment: +1 for more details. Are you using WCF Data Services? What version? (We recommend getting the latest from NuGet.) Can you turn on debugging as per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx and post the error message here? (It can't be the key attribute as you're getting back the feed of users, but the routing comment may have teeth.)

Comment: I have the same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551647/odata-single-result-parameter-not-working), did you find a solution?